# How to make a pyqt gui refresh

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, ros

I am making a GUI in pyqt which gets battery levels for a robot and then displays them. The GUI would therefore have to constantly update its battery level displays (which are displayed using QProgressBar).

However, if I were to put the progress bars in a loop, it makes infinite copies of the graphics and stacks them on top of each other. How might I make the progress bars refresh without making additional copies? Is there a way to delete everything in the loop after each recurrence?

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Make the progress bar a global variable, and have another thread call the update progress method, don't copy the progress bar itself.